# creating dynamic xml in android

Tags: android, xml

In my app I want the xml to be created dynamically because depending on some input data I want different elements. So I started with this example, to create a simple dynamic xml of a TextView and a Spinner. The problem is that I do not see anything in the emulator.

Here is my code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout top = new LinearLayout(this);
        top.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        top.addView(ll);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
        ll.addView(tv);

        String signs[]={"+","-"};
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, signs);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        ll.addView(spinner, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't call `setContentView(yourRootLayout);` that's why you get nothing on screen